# How to split a NSString keeping specific punctuations?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, delimiter, nscharacterset

I need to split a sentence in specific punctuation marks, but keeping these punctuations.

I'm doing it like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *delimeter = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"***"];

sentence  = [sentence  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@",***"];
sentence  = [sentence  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@"!***"];
sentence  = [sentence  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"?***"];
sentence  = [sentence  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@".***"];
sentence  = [sentence  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@":***"];
sentence  = [sentence  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@";***"];

NSArray *sentenceArray = [sentence  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: delimeter];
NSMutableArray *finalSentenceArray = [sentenceArray mutableCopy];
[finalSentenceArray removeObject:@""];
```

But doing like this I'm having empty strings that need to be removed. What is a more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you have to keep the delims. Instead of using `***` as marker, use a single character that is not contained in the text.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!

Comment: This would be a good application for either NSScanner or NSRegularExpression.

Comment: `[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"***"]` returns a character set with one `*`. Use `[sentence  componentsSeparatedByString:@"***"]` instead. Are the punctuation marks followed by a space?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, the sentences are followed by a space.

Comment: @GerdK I'll take a look at those.